# ReactJs: map state data to checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a grid of checkboxes. I can check a checkbox and fire off the handler which updates an array of values.

My problem is when I browse back to the page I would like to see checkboxes with the value in an array checked as default.

Can anyone please tell me how do this? Many thanks

```
handler: function(e) {

    channel.publish({
        channel: "contact",
        topic: "selectedContact",
        data: {
            id: e.target.attributes['data-ref'].value
        }
    });
},

render: function() {

    var id = this.props.data.id;
    var isSelected = this.props.data.isSelected;

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox"
                checked={isSelected} data-ref={id}
                onClick={this.handler} />
        </div>
    );
},
```

I have my selected state being passed as props:

props: Object
data: Object
contacts: Array[10]
0: Object
Id: 13211,
isSelected: true

I have a screenshot of the state which holds the isSelected value, but I cant find out how to get that value in the checked property of the component? Do I need to map it somehow?

[image]

My initial value is:

this.props.data.isSelected

But the isSelected value is written to the contacts array in the attachment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the checkbox a so-called [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-controlled-components). In short, if you only assigned it the value of some prop (`this.props`), the actual checkbox value would not be able to change, until the component is re-mounted, because the property would never change except when the component is re-mounted with new properties. So you need to add an `onChange` handler and update the component's state whenever it is clicked, so that the component will re-render with the new state.  Something like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {isSelected: this.props.data.isSelected};
},
handleChange: function(e) {
    var selected = !this.state.isSelected;
    this.setState({isSelected: selected});
},
render: function() {

    var id = this.props.data.id;
    var isSelected = this.state.isSelected;

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox"
                checked={isSelected} 
                data-ref={id}
                onClick={this.handler}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am passing the selected state as props, would I be able to map the data to the chekboxes that way? Instead of a seperate state for each componenet?

Comment: Yes if you pass the selected state as a property, you can use that as an initial value so that the checkbox is checked when you first mount the component. But if you only did that, the checkbox would not be able to change its state when the user clicks it, because the prop would still be the same (props don't change). So you would also need to have the internal state for the component so it can be updated and re-rendered when the user clicks the checkbox. That's called a "controlled component" in React, as described on the page I linked.

Comment: Thanks again, I have the value in state, but can't find out how to access that from my component? Attached image too

Comment: Do you want to render one checkbox for each contact? In that case I suggest creating a new component, moving the `onChange` handler and isSelected state there, then in a parent component loop over each contact in this.props.data.contacts and pass that as props. Maybe you should add that as a separate question on Stackoverflow if that is unclear because that doesn't really concern handling the checkbox state or initial value.

Comment: Your "state" is actually a property that you have passed when you rendered your component. It's accessible in `this.props.data.contacts[0].isSelected`. Since `contacts` is an array you probably want to render one checkbox for each contact.

Comment: Thanks again.

Whats confusing me is var isSelected = this.props.data.contacts[0].isSelected; comes out as undefined?

Comment: Do a need to map/ for each the array?

Comment: You probably need to render one checkbox for each contact in the contacts array, yes.